# Observer doesn't fire in component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have next code in a controller:

```
...
  selectedIngredientsIds: [],

  barItemsChanged: Ember.observer('user.barItems.[]', function() {
    let ingredients = [];
    if (this.get('user').get('barItems')) {
      ingredients = this.get('user').get('barItems').map(function(item) {
        return item.ingredientId;
      });
    }

    this.set('selectedIngredientsIds', ingredients);
  })
...
```

And template:

```
  {{ingredient-chooser
      multiple=false
      ingredients=ingredients
      changeIngredients="changeIngredients"
      needToClear=needToClear
      placeholder="Добавить в бар..."
      selectedIngredients=selectedIngredients
      selectedIngredientsIds=selectedIngredientsIds
      ingredientSelected="ingredientSelected" }}
```

And ***ingredient-chooser*** component:

```
...
  selectedIngredients: [],
  selectedIngredientsIds: [],

  selectedIngredientsChanged: Ember.observer('selectedIngredients.[]', function() {
    this.sendAction("changeIngredients", this.get('selectedIngredients'));
  }),

  selectedIngredientsIdsChanged: Ember.observer('selectedIngredientsIds.[]', function() {
    let self = this;
    let ingredients = this.get('selectedIngredientsIds').map(findIngredientByRealId);
    this.set('selectedIngredients', ingredients);
  })
...
```

`barItemsChanged` observer works fine. `selectedIngredientsChanged` also works fine. Even if I check `selectedIngredientsIds` property it shows correct value. But for some reasons `selectedIngredientsIdsChanged` observer never called.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `selectedIngredientsIds` and `selectedIngredients` should probably be computed properties instead. If you want I can suggest the alternative.

Comment: If you didn't make any typo in your application code, I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issues with next code:

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, () => {
      this.set('selectedIngredientsIds', ingredients);
    });
```

instead of:

```
this.set('selectedIngredientsIds', ingredients);
```

I guess because `user.barItems` is part of model, `barItemsChanged` was called before components observers have been initialized.